# How to perform this recursive query to fetch child ids for each id?

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

Consider the following table:

| ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

I want the result as such:

```
1: [2,3,4]
2: [3,4]
3: [4]
4: null
```

(i.e) Since 1 is the parent of 2 which is the parent of 3 and so on...

I tried this query but it requires a value:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE a AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id # I need to get all values instead of a specific value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b."ID"
    FROM "tblName" "b" JOIN "c" ON "c"."id" = "b"."ParentID"
    )
    SELECT * FROM c
```

Comment: Try `select id from "tblNmae' where ParentID is null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all rows, recurse downward while keeping track of the level, then use `array_agg()` to consolidate and `array_remove` to remove the row's "self" id.

```
with recursive walk as (
  select id, parentid, id as start_id, 0 as level
    from tblname
  union all
  select c.id, c.parentid, p.start_id, p.level + 1 as level
    from walk p
         join tblname c on c.parentid = p.id
)
select start_id, array_remove(array_agg(id order by level), start_id) as children 
  from walk
 group by start_id;
```

The `nullif()` is there only to match your spec.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1d9335ad9080b80db50b3c26f1608fea)*

Comment: This is perfection. Thanks a lot!